# Proving pseudometric and metric

Tags: general-topology

Let  be the set of all continuous functions from $[0,1]$ into $ℝ$. For $, \in $, define

$(,)=\sup\limits_{ \in [0,1]}|()−()|$

1. Prove  is a metric.(I have proved all conditions that satisfy a metric for d except for, $d(f,g)=0$ if and only if $f=g$).
2. Is continuity needed?

Comment: With the exact same definition, $d$ can be defined on the larger space of all *bounded* numeric functions defined on $[0, 1]$.

Comment: If $f\neq g$ then for some $x\in [0,1]$ we have $f(x)\neq g(x)$ so $|f(x)-g(x)|>0$ and $d(f,g)>0$.

Answer (score 2):

One direction is easy: if $f=g$, then $|f(x)-g(x)|=0$ for each $x\in[0,1]$, so $d(f,g)=0$. The other takes a little more work. Suppose that $d(f,g)=0$, i.e., that

$$\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|f(x)-g(x)|=0\,.$$

Then $$0\le|f(x)-g(x)|\le 0\tag{1}$$ for each $x\in[0,1]$, so $|f(x)-g(x)|=0$ for each $x\in[0,1]$, and therefore $f(x)=g(x)$ for each $x\in[0,1]$. And that says precisely that $f=g$. Thus, $d(f,g)=0$ iff $f=g$.

Note that I did not use continuity at all: I used only the facts that absolute values are non-negative and that if $A\subseteq\Bbb R$, $u=\sup A$, and $a\in A$, then $a\le u$ to get the inequalities in $(1)$.

Answer (score 1):

If you might be interested, I will describe here a somewhat more general construction. Consider an arbitrary metric space $(Y, d)$ and define $\mathscr{B}$ to be the collection of all subsets of $Y$ which are bounded with respect to $d$. Explicitly, this means that:
$$\mathscr{B}\colon=\left\{M \subseteq Y|\ \mathrm{diam}M<\infty\right\}$$
where the diameter of an arbitrary subset $M \subseteq Y$ is by definition given by:
$$\begin{align*}
\mathrm{diam}M\colon=\begin{cases}
0, &M=\varnothing\\
\displaystyle\sup_{x,y \in M}d(x, y), &M \neq \varnothing.
\end{cases}
\end{align*}$$
Note the fact that $\mathscr{B}$ is closed with respect to *finite* unions (i.e. any union of finitely many bounded sets remains bounded).

Let us also consider an arbitrary (nonempty, to avoid technicalities in the subsequent definitions) set $X$ and introduce the set:
$$\mathrm{Bd}(X, d)\colon=\left\{f \colon X \to Y|\ \mathrm{Im}f \in \mathscr{B}\right\}$$
of all *bounded* maps from $X$ to $Y$ (again, boundedness is considered with respect to the fixed metric $d$). Given any two bounded maps $f, g \in \mathrm{Bd}(X, d)$, let us fix a certain $a \in X$ (since $X \neq \varnothing$) and notice that for any $x \in X$ we have:
$$d(f(x), g(x)) \leqslant d(f(x), f(a))+d(f(a), g(a))+d(g(a), g(x))\leqslant \mathrm{diam}\left(\mathrm{Im}f\right)+d(f(a), g(a))+\mathrm{diam}\left(\mathrm{Im}g\right),$$
which means that the set $\{d(f(x), g(x)\}_{x \in X}$ is nonempty (once again since $X \neq \varnothing$) and has an upper bound. It thus follows that this set of distances has a supremum which is furthermore positive (as a side-note, by positive I mean $\geqslant 0$ whereas $>0$ I express as *strictly* positive), since $0 \leqslant d(f(a),g(a)) \leqslant \displaystyle\sup_{x \in X}d(f(x), g(x))$.

The above justifies the correctness of defining the following map:
$$\begin{align*}
&d' \colon \mathrm{Bd}(X, d) \times \mathrm{Bd}(X, d) \to [0, \infty)\\
&d'(f, g)=\sup_{x \in X}d(f(x), g(x)),
\end{align*}$$
map which we are going to argue is a *metric* on the set $\mathrm{Bd}(X, d)$. By definition, $d'$ takes positive real values and we must ascertain that the three axioms comprised in the definition of a metric are satisfied by $d'$:

1. $d'(f, g)=0 \Leftrightarrow f=g$ for any bounded maps $f, g \in \mathrm{Bd}(X, d)$. If $f=g$, it is clear that $d'(f, g)=\displaystyle\sup_{x \in X}0=\sup\{0\}=0$. Conversely, assuming that $f, g$ are such that $d'(f, g)=0$, we gather by definition of $d'$ that the relations $0 \leqslant d(f(x), g(x)) \leqslant d'(f, g)=0$ hold for any $x \in X$. Since $d$ itself is a metric, these relations entail $d(f(x), g(x))=0$ and subsequently $f(x)=g(x)$ for every $x \in X$, which means exactly that $f=g$ (the two maps have the same domain of definition $X$, the same codomain $Y$ and the same correspondence law).
2. The symmetry of $d'$ follows immediately from the symmetry of $d$, since we have the obvious equality $\{d(f(x), g(x))\}_{x \in X}=\{d(g(x), f(x))\}_{x \in X}$.
3. The triangle inequality: given three bounded maps $f, g, h \in \mathrm{Bd}(X, d)$, the triangle inequality applied to the original metric $d$ entails that:
   $$d(f(x), h(x)) \leqslant d(f(x), g(x))+d(g(x), h(x)) \leqslant d'(f, g)+d'(g, h)$$
   for any $x \in X$, in other words that $d'(f, g)+d'(g, h)$ is an upper bound for the set $\left\{d(f(x), h(x)\right\}_{x \in X}$. This further leads to the conclusion that $d'(f, g) \leqslant d'(f, g)+d'(g, h)$, establishing the triangle inequality for $d'$ as well.

---

The above construction as you can see is possible in a very general setting, you only need a metric space and an arbitrary set for it. A further elaboration of this construction can be conceived in the case where the domain of definition $X$ comes equipped with a topology $\mathscr{T}$ rendering $(X, \mathscr{T})$ into a *compact* space (in compactness I do not include the $T_2$ separation axiom). In this instance, the set of all continuous maps between the space $(X, \mathscr{T})$ and the space $(Y, \mathscr{M})$ -- $\mathscr{M}$ being the *metric* topology induced by the metric $d$ -- is a subset of $\mathrm{Bd}(X, d)$ (because any continuous map defined on a compact space must have bounded image), subset which is furthermore *closed* with respect to the metric topology induced by $d'$ on $\mathrm{Bd}(X, d)$. This is indeed a statement for which continuity is indispensible.